# How to print SMTP debug in other location?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I'm trying to display the PHPMailer SMTP debug info. **This is okay** if the email failed but two emails are sent if success.

```
global $phpmailer;
$send = wp_mail( $to, 'Test Email', $message );

$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 3;

ob_start();
$send = wp_mail( $to, 'Test Email', $message );
$smtp_debug = ob_get_clean();


echo "<pre>"; print_r( $smtp_debug ); echo "</pre>";
```

**If I remove the first wp_mail()**:

```
global $phpmailer;

$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 3;

ob_start();
$send = wp_mail( $to, 'Test Email', $message );
$smtp_debug = ob_get_clean();


echo "<pre>"; print_r( $smtp_debug ); echo "</pre>";
```

It gives the warning:

> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in line:  `$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 3;`

**If I remove the second wp_mail()**, the `$smtp_debug` will be empty.

So, how to only send one email on success and also grab the error on failure?

Comment: did you initialized phpmailer class? This is starting point `$phpmailer= new PHPMailer(true);` then `$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 3;`

Answer (score 1):

To gain control over PHPMailer's debug output, you can inject a callable into the `Debugoutput` property, as [the source code says](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L403):

```
$phpmailer->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
    echo "debug level $level; message: $str";
};
```

That's just an example - you can do whatever you like inside that closure - write to a log file, send data to an external API, etc. This is a much better and less complicated approach than using output buffering.

As @Akam said, The `default object` warning you're getting means that the `$phpmailer` variable is empty (e.g. NULL, or undefined), and thus you're setting a non-existent property, resulting in the warning.

Check that `$phpmailer` contains what you think it should (i.e. track down where it is originally created) and make sure that code gets run before you try to use the instance.